# Using Perl to rename files in a directory

Tags: perl, file, directory, rename

I'd like to take a directory and for all email (*.msg) files, remove the 'RE ' at the beginning. I have the following code but the rename fails.

```
opendir(DIR, 'emails') or die "Cannot open directory";
@files = readdir(DIR);
closedir(DIR);

for (@files){
    next if $_ !~ m/^RE .+msg$/;
    $old = $_;
    s/RE //;
    rename($old, $_) or print "Error renaming: $old\n";
}
```

Comment: If you print the error ($!) you might get an idea of what's wrong...

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. The error is 'No such file or directory'. I am surprised because the $old file name is accurate.

Comment: Note that `rename` does not enjoy cross-platform support, whereas `File::Copy` 's `move` function does

Comment: @Zaid: but does it also preserve permissions, cross-platform?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If your `./emails` directory contains these files:

```
1.msg
2.msg
3.msg
```

then your `@files` will look something like `('.', '..', '1.msg', '2.msg', '3.msg')` but your `rename` wants names like `'emails/1.msg'`, `'emails/2.msg'`, etc. So you can [`chdir`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chdir.html) before renaming:

```
chdir('emails');
for (@files) {
    #...
}
```

You'd probably want to check the `chdir` return value too.

Or add the directory names yourself:

```
rename('emails/' . $old, 'emails/' . $_) or print "Error renaming $old: $!\n";
# or rename("emails/$old", "emails/$_") if you like string interpolation
# or you could use map if you like map
```

You might want to combine your directory reading and filtering using [`grep`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html):

```
my @files = grep { /^RE .+msg$/ } readdir(DIR);
```

or even this:

```
opendir(DIR, 'emails') or die "Cannot open directory";
for (grep { /^RE .+msg$/ } readdir(DIR)) {
    (my $new = $_) =~ s/^RE //;
    rename("emails/$_", "emails/$new") or print "Error renaming $_ to $new: $!\n";
}
closedir(DIR);
```

Answer (score 5):

You seem to be assuming [`glob`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html)-like behavior rather than than [`readdir`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readdir.html)-like behavior.

The underlying `readdir` system call returns just the filenames within the directory, and will include two entries `.` and `..`.  This carries through to the `readdir` function in Perl, just to give a bit more detail on mu's answer.

Alternately, there's not much point to using `readdir` if you're collecting all the results in an array anyways.

```
@files = glob('emails/*');
```

Comment: +1 for reminding me that `glob` exists. The downside to `glob` is that it complicates the name mangling a little bit due to the presence of the `'emails/'` prefix, that's a pretty minor problem and trivial to deal with though.

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned, your script fails because of the path you expect and the script uses are not the same.

I would suggest a more transparent usage. Hardcoding a directory is not a good idea, IMO. As I learned one day when I made a script to alter some original files, with the hardcoded path, and a colleague of mine thought this would be a nice script to borrow to alter his copies. Ooops!

**Usage:**

```
perl script.pl "^RE " *.msg
```

i.e. regex, then a file glob list, where the path is denoted in relation to the script, e.g. `*.msg`, `emails/*.msg` or even `/home/pat/emails/*.msg /home/foo/*.msg`. (multiple globs possible)

Using the absolute paths will leave the user with no doubt as to which files he'll be affecting, and it will also make the script reusable.

**Code:**

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.10;
use File::Copy qw(move);

my $rx = shift;   # e.g. "^RE "

if ($ENV{OS} =~ /^Windows/) {  # Patch for Windows' lack of shell globbing
    @ARGV = map glob, @ARGV;
}

for (@ARGV) {
    if (/$rx/) {
        my $new = s/$rx//r;  # Using non-destructive substitution
        say "Moving $_ to $new ...";
        move($_, $new) or die $!;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I really like this idea. I seem to be getting an error on the line my $new = s/$rx//r. Output is 'bareword found where operator expected near "s/$rx//r" and syntax error near the same

Comment: @JP. Oh, that might be due to your perl version.. which version do you use?

Comment: @JP. `corelist "/r"` gives me `/r was first released with perl v5.8.9`, so the non-destructive option was not available in earlier versions.

Comment: @JP. So that should work then. The code works for me. Did you use `"^RE "` as your regex? There should be no slashes in the regex. Either that, or there was some error in the copy/paste to your end. You might check to make sure that you can use `/r` and `say` with your version.

Comment: @JP. If it is the `/r` option, it is easy to work around. Simply replace that line with `my $new = $_; $new =~ s/$rx//;`.

Comment: TLP, `corelist "/r"` is wrong as it takes module names only. [The `r` modifier was first in 5.13.2.](http://p3rl.org/perl5132delta#Non-destructive-substitution).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if the regex fits the specifig name of the files, but in one line this could be done with:

`perl -E'for (</path/to/emails*.*>){ ($new = $_) =~ s/(^RE)(.*$)/$2/; say  $_." -> ".$new}`

(`say ...` is nice for testing, just replace it with `rename $_,$new` or `rename($_,$new)` )

1. `<*.*>` read every file in the current directory
2. `($new = $_) =~` saves the following substitution in `$new` and leaves `$_` as intact
3. `(^RE)` save this match in $1 (optional) and just match files with "RE" at the beginning
4. `(.*$)` save everything until and including the end ($) of the line -> into $2
5. substitute the match with the string in`$2`